# Flutter Bloc State

Tags: flutter, bloc

Just start with bloc and looking for improvement.
I wonder if I did it okay here, Because I don't know which state should I Emit.
it is not update when I add or remove item from list

[image: My Cubit Class]

Comment: If anyone could provide a source with (Dio/HTTP) request where could I learn is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Bloc triggers a state update whenever the old state does not equal the new one.
Just adding or removing an item to a list is not enough.

To achieve this you can either use the package [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) or manually override the equals method of your state class (the first way is cleaner and more secure).

I also suggest to take a look at the [official documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/coreconcepts?id=state-changes-1) for the bloc library for state changes.

Comment: Hello, I already use Equatable. when I remove or add item to the list, Equatable  should see the diff right?

Comment: @ChhilyLim personally I have never used equatable exactly for this reason. I prefer the old, slower way of having to override Equals and HashCode. It gives me more control

Comment: Hi, I have found the way to update the list. thank you for helped!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution while playing around!

[image: Updated]